# javascript replace method works except when in loop it escapes html

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, html-escape-characters

This code works perfectly to replace a string with some html:

```
$('.active_admin_comment_body').each(function(comment_index){
    the_string = $(this).text().replace("#Excitement", "<span style=\"background-color: lightgrey;\">#Excitement</span>");
     $(this).html(the_string);
)};
```

The problem with the code above is it only works to replace one value.  I have an array of values, so I wrote the following code to loop through the array and then modify each comment with a value from the array:

```
$('.active_admin_comment_body').each(function(comment_index){
    hashtags = ["#Excitement", "#Sad News", "#Moderate"];
    comment = $(this);
    $.each(hashtags, function(index, value){
        new_comment = comment.text().replace(value, "<span style='background-color: lightgrey;'>" + value + "</span>");
        comment.html(new_comment);
    });
});
```

The first block of code works 100%.  The second block of code only works if you remove the html inside of the replace method.  How do I get the second block of code to work?

Comment: If you want to replace all matches use `str.replace(/textToReplace/g, 'replaceWith');`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand your comment.  I tried switching `replace` with `replaceWith` but nothing changed.  Also I looked at the documentation for `replaceWith` and it seems like that's for DOM elements, not particular text.

Comment: @Philip7899 That's not what @YordanNikolov said. He is pointing out that you should change `"#Excitement"` to `/#Excitement/g` or to `RegExp("#Excitement", "g")`. The `g` means to replace all instances instead of replacing the first and then stopping.

Comment: At the risk of giving a jerk answer, the proper solution is to ditch your code and use a templating engine.

Comment: I think that `comment.text().replace...` should be changed to `comment.html().replace...`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the `text()` method. When you call it, it only returns the text inside the element, inadvertently undoing any HTML that have already been put in.

```
$('.active_admin_comment_body').each(function(comment_index){
    var hashtags = ["#Excitement", "#Sad News", "#Moderate"];
    var comment = $(this);
    $.each(hashtags, function(index, value){
        // I changed text() to html() in the next line.
        var new_comment = comment.html().replace(value, "<span style='background-color: lightgrey;'>" + value + "</span>");
        comment.html(new_comment);
    });
});
```

You should also note that `replace` will only replace the first match. For example, `"foo bar foo".replace("foo", "baz")` returns `"baz bar foo"`; you can see that only the first `foo` is replaced. If you want to replace all instances, you need to specify the `g` option; `"foo bar foo".replace(RegExp("foo", "g"), "baz")` returns `"baz bar baz"`. In your code:

```
$('.active_admin_comment_body').each(function(comment_index){
    var hashtags = ["#Excitement", "#Sad News", "#Moderate"];
    var comment = $(this);
    $.each(hashtags, function(index, value){
        // I changed text() to html() and added the RegExp constructor.
        var new_comment = comment.html().replace(RegExp(value, "g"), "<span style='background-color: lightgrey;'>" + value + "</span>");
        comment.html(new_comment);
    });
});
```

If you change the items inside `hashtags` to include strings that are not hashtags, you may need to escape certain characters with a `\` so that they aren't interpreted as special characters. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for a table of characters that need to be escaped. The `#` sign is not one of the special characters, so if you stick to just hashtags, then you don't need to worry about this.

Finally, instead of using a loop to change multiple strings, you may want to use a callback replace:

```
$('.active_admin_comment_body').each(function(comment_index){
    var hashtags = ["#Excitement", "#Sad News", "#Moderate"];
    var comment = $(this);
    var new_comment = comment.html().replace(/#(Excitement|Sad News|Moderate)/g, function(tag){
        return "<span style='background-color: lightgrey;'>" + tag + "</span>";
    });
    comment.html(new_comment);
});
```

You'll also notice that I added the `var` keyword to your code; this makes your variables local instead of global. This does not change the functionality of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) and [`new RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that joins the array using `|` for an OR

```js
var hashtags = ["#Excitement", "#Sad News", "#Moderate"];

$('.active_admin_comment_body').html(function(_, txt) {
  var reg = new RegExp('(' + hashtags.join('|') + ')', 'g');
  return txt.replace(reg, '<span class="lightgrey">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
.lightgrey{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='active_admin_comment_body'>
  Test1 #Excitement
</div>
<div class='active_admin_comment_body'>
  Test2 #Sad News
</div>
<div class='active_admin_comment_body'>
  Test3 #Moderate
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

textToReplace is `"#Excitement"` & replaceWith is `"<span style=\"background-color: lightgrey;\">#Excitement</span>"` in your case it will become

```
the_string = $(this).text().replace(/#Excitement/g, "<span style=\"background-color: lightgrey;\">#Excitement</span>");

new_comment = comment.text();
$.each(hashtags, function(index, value){
        new_comment = new_comment.replace(value, "<span style='background-color: lightgrey;'>" + value + "</span>");
    });
comment.html(new_comment);
```

Updated

Comment: Thanks but I got it to work already with just `#excitement`.  I'm trying to get the second block of code to work where you loop through the array

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were actually just missing one small thing. The way you loop was working it was only replacing the last one in the array. Changing the last value in the array caused it to switch which one was working.

Just matched the hashtag to the current string and everything is in order.

Only thing added to your code is the if statement, comparing for a match.

```js
$(function(){
$('.active_admin_comment_body').each(function(comment_index){
    hashtags = ["#Excitement", "#Sad News", "#Moderate"];
    comment = $(this);
    $.each(hashtags, function(index, value){
     if(comment.text().includes(value)){
       new_comment = comment.text().replace(value, "<span style='background-color: lightgrey;'>" + value + "  </span>");
        comment.html(new_comment);
      }
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='active_admin_comment_body'>
Test1 #Excitement
</div>
<div class='active_admin_comment_body'>
Test2 #Sad News
</div>
<div class='active_admin_comment_body'>
Test3 #Moderate
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75e0o36s/